# php getting big data from url - optimise

Tags: php

I am using `file_get_contents` to get 1 million records from URL and output the results which is in json format and I can't go for pagination and currently working by increasing my memory. Is there any other solution for this?

Comment: The URL that you are calling is yours? I mean cant you re program your URL that returns data in paginated way. For optimization there are so many ways.

Comment: Use a stream based solution e.g. https://github.com/salsify/jsonstreamingparser

Comment: Sorry but 1 million rows is not big data.

Answer (score 1):

> If you're processing large amounts of data, **fscanf** will probably prove
>   valuable and more efficient than, say, using file followed by a split
>   and **sprintf** command. In contrast, if you're simply echoing a large
>   amount of text with little modification, file, **file_get_contents**, or
>   readfile might make more sense. This would likely be the case if
>   you're using PHP for caching or even to create a makeshift proxy
>   server.

More 
[The right way to read files with PHP](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-readfiles/)